# How to show conform message dialog box using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

i have develop a small asp.net web application in this i have a  in this buttob i am using onclick event for page redirect to another page

```
  <a class="details-link" data-role="listview-link" onclick="AfterChangestatus('<%=Getstatus[0] %>')"><%=Getstatus[1] %></a>

        function AfterChangestatus(DocStatusvalues) {

        $("#place_of_loading_image").show();
        window.location.href = "AppointmentDetails.aspx?changedropdown=" + DocStatusvalues;

    }
```

this is working for me.

**Now i want add conform message box in the same a href with button yes/no ,when i click yes it will redirect to the page else it will stay on that page and close the pop window**

is it possible please help me..

Comment: @Neil-McGuigan Down votes for helping newbies? How'd you learn to program?

Comment: Hi Michael Rice You are right and ur oding is working fine for me.Thank you very much to you.

Comment: May i know why voting down to my Question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function AfterChangestatus(DocStatusvalues) {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure?");

    if (r == true)
    {
        $("#place_of_loading_image").show();
        window.location.href = "AppointmentDetails.aspx?changedropdown=" + DocStatusvalues;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi... this is helped to me it's working fine that what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.confirm("Are you sure?")){
    // do stuff
}else{
    // not confirmed stuff
}
```